# can you connect two or more controllers?

Tags: bluetooth

Is it possible to connect two or more bluetooth controllers to one android tablet? I am wanting to emulate some games that are four players and I want to know if three friends and I can all play together?

Comment: Well, I don't think that can be done only one bluetooth controllers can be connected to one Android tablets. I would suggest wait a little more while on this one maybe other members have some trick to do that... but as far as I know chances are very much less !

Comment: You can connect multiple bluetooth SENDING devices to an Android tablet (but it depends on the tablet), you cannot connect multiple devices that can receive any data (e.g. the PS4 controller). From my trying it on about 5 devices it does not work for gaming at all. There may be a way to force this but the tablets all drop devices.

Comment: If you want to connect multiple controllers, it might be possible to use OTG and connect wired controllers to your Android. That way you could technically connect multiple controllers..

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of an opinionated, and caveated answer.

According to the [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) you can indeed

> "Manage multiple connections"

It seems to be the case than an Android tablet can connect with multiple Bluetooth devices **sending** data only, but Bluetooth devices that can also **receive** data will only pair with one device.

From my trying this on:

Galaxy Tab
Nexus 9
Nexus 7
Galaxy S5  (phone not tablet obviously)
Nexus 10
Galaxy Note

It only allows one controller and disconnects the others. We had some patchy performance with two working, but Bluetooth is not a good technology for multiple connections like this.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can contact up too 4 controllers simultaneously but the way I achieved this was with a rooted note 4 just install sixaxis and there is support for multi play...
I hdmi into tv and vs my mates with ps3 controllers (work best, even non genuin) also if you are using emulators n64 emulators have multi support inbuilt but you still need sixaxis to connect through Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

outdated answers.
It's perfectly possible with at least Android 6.1 and above to connect up to 4 bluetooth controllers.

Just pair the first controller, **turn it off**, pair the second controller - and turn the first on again.